# How to add sound effects to PCM buffered audio in C++

Tags: c++, audio, effects

I have an `int16_t[]` buffer with PCM raw audio data and I want to apply some effects (like echo, reverb, gain...) into it.

I thought that SoX or similar can do the trick for me, but SoX only works with files and other similar libraries that supports adding sound effects seems to add the effects only when the sound is played. So my problem with this is that I want to apply the effect to the samples into my buffer without playing them.

I have never worked with audio, but reading about PCM data I have learned that I can apply gain multiplying each sample value, for example. But I'm looking for any library or relatively easy algorithms that I can use directly in my buffer to get the sound effects applied.

I'm sure there are a lot of solutions to my problem out there if you know what to look for, but it's my first time with audio "processing" and I'm lost, as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone like me, interested in learning DSP related to audio processing with C++ I want to share my little research results and opinion, and perhaps save you some time :)

After trying several DSP libraries, finally I have found The [Synthesis ToolKit in C++ (STK)](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/), an open-source library that offer easy and clear interfaces and easy to understand code that you can dive in to learn about various basic DSP algorithms.

So, I recommend to anyone who is starting out and have no previous experience to take a look at this library.

Answer (score 1):

Your `int16_t[]` buffer contains a sequence of samples. They represent instantaneous amplitude levels. Think of them as the voltage to apply to the speaker at the corresponding instant in time.  They are signed numbers with values in the range (-32767,32767]. A stream of constant zeros means silence.  A stream of constant -32000 (for example) also means silence, but it will eventually burn your your speaker coil. The position in the array represents time, and the value of each sample represents voltage.

If you want to mix two sample streams together, for example to apply a chirp, you get yourself a sample stream with the chirp in it (record a bird or something). You then add the two sounds sample by sample.

You can do a super-cheesy reverb effect by taking your original sound buffer, lowering its volume (perhaps by dividing all the samples by a constant), and adding it back to your original stream, but shifting the samples by a tenth of a second's worth of array position.

Those are the basics of audio processing.  Things get very sophisticated indeed. This field is known as "digital signal processing" and there are plenty of books on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I have been playing with the buffer and been able to get gain, wah-wah and echo effects, but now I'm reading about vocoders and it becomes complicated. Do you know any C/C++ library I can use for this?

Comment: A web search for open-source audio signal processing turns up quite a few candidates.  E. g. http://essentia.upf.edu/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either with hacking the audio buffer and trying to do some effects like gain and threshold with simple math operations or do it correct using proper DSP algorithms. If you wish to do it correct, I would recommend using the Speex Library. It's open source and and well tested. www (dot)speex (dot)org. The code should compile on MSVC or linux with minimal effort. This is the fastest way to get a good audio code working with proper DSP techniques. Your code would look like .. please read the AEC example.

```
 st = speex_echo_state_init(NN, TAIL);
 den = speex_preprocess_state_init(NN, sampleRate);
 speex_echo_ctl(st, SPEEX_ECHO_SET_SAMPLING_RATE, &sampleRate);
 speex_preprocess_ctl(den, SPEEX_PREPROCESS_SET_ECHO_STATE, st);
```

You need to setup the states, the code testecho includes these.